# Reset the src of <audio> on Edge

Tags: javascript, audio, microsoft-edge, audio-recording, src

I'm having issues with the audio tag on edge browser.

I'm trying to clear the source of an audio tag that I use to play a recorded sound with an input device. You can choose if you want to send or not the audio, is optional, so I'm trying to give the option of deleting the source of the audio when the user click the trash button, I want to clear the input and the preview audio tag. All works fine in other browsers but on Edge when I clean the audio source of the preview audio tag it shows a message of "This type of audio file is not supported" instead of restarting the time to 0 or disable it like when it starts.

Anyone have an idea of how I can do to achieve that?

```js
var source = "http://d.mimp3.eu/i/mS6mfOGoji8nmNKoba6Zg653/system-of-a-down-lonely-day.mp3";

audio = document.getElementById('audioToChange');

function addSource(){
 audio.setAttribute("src", source );
}
function removeSource(){
 audio.removeAttribute("src");
}
function clearSource () {
 audio.setAttribute("src", "" );
}
function clearANDremove () {
 audio.setAttribute("src", "" );
 audio.removeAttribute("src");
}
```

```html
<audio id="audioToChange" controls src=""></audio>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="addSource()" value="Add Source" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="removeSource()" value="Remove Source" />
<input type="button" onclick="clearSource()" value="Clear Source" />
<input type="button" onclick="clearANDremove()" value="Clear & Remove Source" />
```

I will let a simple example to show what I'm trying to explain.

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vs79yjv/5/)